# Extending a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
function foo(){
    var myValue = 5;
    var myOtherValue = 1;
    return {
        getValue: function(){
            return [myValue, myOtherValue];
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can extend/overwrite this function somehow without touching the original function so that when I call `getValue()` I get `[SOME OTHER VALUE I CHOOSE, myOtherValue]`?

If not, can I do it at the instance level?

```
var myFoo = new foo();
myFoo.getValue = function(){
    return [0, myOtherValue]; // how to I access myOtherValue?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to modify foo, you can do this:

```
function foo(){
    var myValue = 5;
    var myOtherValue = 1;
    return {
        getValue: function(){
            return [myValue, myOtherValue];
        }
    }
}

var myFoo = new foo();
//move getValue to _getValue
myFoo._getValue = myFoo.getValue;

//do custom getValue
myFoo.getValue = function(){
    return [0, myFoo._getValue()[1]]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

`myOtherValue` is only defined in the scope of `foo`.

---

You could have to rewrite to something like this:

```
function foo(){
    var myValue = 5;

    return {
        myOtherValue: 1,
        getValue: function(){
            return [myValue, this.myOtherValue];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you *could* do:

```
var myFoo = new foo();
myFoo.getValue = function(){
    return [0, myFoo.myOtherValue]; 
}
```

Comment: You could proxy requests to `foo` and still be able to do it. May be difficult, but it's possible.

Comment: @squid314 can you explain please?

Comment: Give me a bit, I'm making an answer of my own to show it.

Comment: Did you test the code in your edit? I still don't think that works because of the scope.

Comment: Ooops. Sorry about that. Updated @Kyle

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo(){
    var myValue = 5;
    var myOtherValue = 1;
    return {
        getValue: function(){
            return [myValue, myOtherValue];
        }
    }
}

var myFoo = new foo();
var storeOriginal= myFoo.getValue;
myFoo.getValue = function(){
   //your code
   storeOriginal();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a variable in a closure. However, you can define the new function to delegate to the original function to access it:

```
var myFoo = new foo();
myFoo.getValue = (function (original) {
    return function(){
        var val = original();
        val[0] = 0;
        return val;
    };
}(myFoo.getValue));
```

Here is a fiddle of this solution so you can try it out yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/6Ux92/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo() {
    .. original stuff ..
}


var hidden_foo = foo;
function decorator() {
    var internal = hidden_foo();

    // here is the proxy object
    return {
        getValue: function() {
            return [SOME OTHER VALUE I CHOOSE, internal.getValue()[1]];
        }
    }
}
// overwrite the original function with our decorated version
foo = decorator;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
function myFoo() {
    var vals = foo().getValue();
    return {
         getValue : function(){
             return [0, vals[1]]
         }
    }
}
```

`vals[1]` is obviously `myOtherValue`

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap this function with a decorator function:

```
 var decorator = function() {
   var someNewValue = ...;
   var myOtherValue = foo().getValue()[1];
   return [someNewValue, myOtherValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function foo(){
    this.myValue = 5;
    var myOtherValue = 1;
    return {
        getValue: function(){
            return [this.myValue, myOtherValue];
        }
    }
}

var bar = new foo();
bar.myValue = "whatever";
```